# Python Script Exe Doesn't run

Tags: python

i have turned my script into an EXE with pyinstaller.I am trying to run the exe, but all it does is bring up a black window (cmd or something similar) and then closes, the script should open a tkinter window. Does anyone know what i can do?

Below is my code, i have no idea why it doesnt load. If i run the script through idle that works

```html
from tkinter import *
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

today = date.today()
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%y")


def save_info():
    date_info = d1_var.get()
    time_info = currentTime.get()
    station_info = "4"
    serialNumber_info = serialNumber.get()
    errorType_info = errorType.get()
    operator_info = operator.get()

    file = open("test.csv", "a")
    file.write(date_info)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(time_info)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(station_info)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(serialNumber_info)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(operator_info)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(errorType_info)
    file.write("\n")

    serialNumber_entry.delete(0,END)
    operator_entry.delete(0,END)


screen = Tk()
d1_var = StringVar(screen,d1)
currentTime = StringVar(screen,current_time)

screen.geometry("500x250")
screen.title("Error Log TS1")
heading = Label(text = "Error Log Form TS1", bg = "grey", fg = "black", width = "500", height = "3")
heading.pack()

serialNumber_text = Label(text = "Serial Number:",)
operator_text = Label(text = "Operator:",)

serialNumber_text.place(x = 13, y = 100)
operator_text.place(x = 13, y = 130)

serialNumber = StringVar()
operator = StringVar()

serialNumber_entry = Entry(textvariable = serialNumber, width = "10")
operator_entry = Entry(textvariable = operator, width = "5")

serialNumber_entry.place(x = 100, y = 102)
operator_entry.place(x = 70, y = 132)

errorType = StringVar()

radio1 = Radiobutton(screen,text="Initialisation Error",variable=errorType,value="Initialisation Error")
radio2 = Radiobutton(screen,text="No Power Cable",variable=errorType,value="No Power Cable")
radio3 = Radiobutton(screen,text="Comms Error",variable=errorType,value="Comms Error")

radio1.place(x=250,y=70)
radio2.place(x=250,y=110)
radio3.place(x=250,y=150)

register = Button(screen,text = "Register", width = "30", height = "2", command = save_info, bg = "grey")
register.place(x = 200, y = 190)
```

Comment: The most likely cause of this issue is that you didn't bundle the correct libraries with your executable. Make sure you include the correct versions of Tkinter, as well as any other libraries your script requires when you build your executable with PyInstaller. @CyberJack2022

Comment: @Teddy even if i disabled the console, the program should run. and what you mean by "comma d"

Answer (score 1):

Open the folder containing your exe in file explorer, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and type `cmd` instead of full path, this will open command line in your current folder.

Type the name of you exe and run, this will not close the window and you'll see the error happening.

Comment: It runs but nothing happens, and then cmd just allows me to do more commands

Comment: @CyberJack2022 well, at least least now we know it does not show any errors… What's next? Do prints for any possible error in your code before turning it to exe to understand what happens.

Comment: I found the issue, i needed screen.mainloop()